# How can I remove the + button in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I press the + button that I marked with red, two things that I marked with green open. As on the left in my respective installed plugins. How can I remove this + button?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBMeP.png)

How can I fix this situation? I would be glad if you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a `Comment` button related to commenting on Pull Requests.  You can disable it from appearing by disabling this setting:

```
Comments: Visible
```

Those types of Comments can still be viewed in the `Comments View` for which there is an accompanying setting (search for "Comments View" in the Settings UI) that controls when that view opens.